# yii framework reporting tool

Tags: yii, jasper-reports, reporting

I´m evaluating in using YII framework for an application. This app has 2 requirements very important. First is Reporting. I have to make a lot of Reports and subreports. The Second is that reports have to be exported to word, pdf and xls.

I understand that PHP is not very friendly with reporting tools. I think the best could be Jasper Reports?. But that tool can help me with that 2 points?

Have you use reporting tools with advance reports in php? could you give me an advice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am working on JasperReports for the last few months. Its extremely user friendly. The 2 points which you mentioned are very well covered in Jasper. You can do 'n' number of reports, subreports, adhocs, olaps,charts and many more. Exporting options are great. There are around 11 formats in which you can export the reports. I have not used yii or any other reporting tool. For reporting and advanced reporting options, Jasperreports works brilliant. You may want to check out this [link](http://www.jaspersoft.com/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

I am doing a Yii project at the moment. I have not used a great deal of reporting tools, and have not checked out Jasper yet.
But for excel the best reporting tool I have found has been PHPExcel. I extended the factory and built my own code around it to work with my data.

Also if you want to report into MS Word, it might be easier to write your data to RTF files.

I have found PDF's and Text/Word Documents tend to not be too flash for reporting. Excel seems to be the most useful so far. I use PHPExcel with both openoffice on linux and MS Excel and I write all my own reports.

Cheers
Daz

Answer (score 0):

Jasper Reports is a great tool for reporting but it require Java and the integration with PHP require the Java bridge which may not be accessible specially in shared hosting, a good alternative is [PHPJasperXML](http://www.simit.com.my/?q=PHPJasperXML), which takes Jasper Reports and render them on PHP natively, also it exports to PDF and Excel.

Comment: You don't need Java Bridge. JasperServer has SOAP and REST API to serve reports with any backend technology http://www.slideshare.net/marianolu/embedding-jaspersoft-into-your-php-application

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it could help but exists https://github.com/cossou/JasperPHP in the Laravel framework, somebody could adapt it for [Yii2](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2) and use it with composer.